# Determining angle of view from an image with a square or checkerboard in the background.

Tags: 3d, computer-vision

I take a picture of a square of known dimension (let's say 1x1 units) with the camera at an unknown angle relative to the plane of the rectangle. (The distance to the rectangle is also unknown, but irrelevant since the dimension of the square is known.) Without performing any automated image procession to "find" the square, (I'll be processing "by hand"), I want to estimate the angle "off axis" that the camera was relative to the plane of the square when the image was acquired. I am ignoring lens-based distortion for the time being. In other words I am assuming the camera has been calibrated or there is no distortion.

The square will take the form of a trapezoid in the resulting image, the dimensions of which will be a function of the angle that the camera was "off axis". If the primary axis of the camera (a line drawn through the lens perpendicular to the photosensor), is perpendicular to the square, the square will remain square. If the angle of the primary axis of the camera is NOT perpendicular to the plane of the square, the square will appear trapezoidal in the resulting image. The dimensions of that trapezoid reveal the angle "off axis".

What is the math involved once I have the dimensions of the 'trapezoid'?

Answer (score 1):

You are applying some sort of projection from a 3D world to the 2D screen of a camera.

There are different transformations and camera models ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1814927/86776)), I would suggest to consult a good introduction to 3D computer graphics, like Foley-Van Dam.

This will usually result in a transformation matrix using homogeneous coordinates. One can then investigate how a square gets transformed.
The goal would be to invert the transformation, to reconstruct the square from the image. Due to the loss of information, this invertation might not be possible in a unique fashion for all geometric configurations.

Comment: I was thinking if simple geometry and the fact that magnification is inversely proportional to distance , might be enough..

Comment: That sounds like the pin hole camera model in the linked question. It features the pin hole / focal point in distance $d$ and projects onto the plane $z=0$. Now have a look how each of the orthogonal sides in world coordinates get mapped to the projection plane.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will look at the citation.

Comment: Upon further reflection, I realized that the problem is really one of "rotation". When moving off only one axis, the problem is 'simple-er', but when off-axis in two axes, the problem complicates significantly, I think. If one considers the primary axis of the camera as a "rod" attached to the center of the field of view, then 'off-axis' movement of the camera is actually rotation along that 'rod'.

Comment: I am suspicious that "simple" geometry is insufficient to provide a solution and linear algebra will be required. That's not a problem per se, I was just hoping for "simple" because I need to perform these operations in quasi-real time on a cell-phone camera. "Simple" translates to "faster". Conversely, "complex" translates to "slower". Maybe too slow for practical application.

Comment: I appreciate the idea that this is SORT OF a 3d projection to 2d projection, because of the Z (distance) axis. However, I think it is simplified by the planar (2d) nature of the checkerboard and the lack of need of distance info because of the known dimension of the squares. In my head I imagine that the relationships of the sides and angles of the transformed square (2d) provide sufficient information to derive a solution. I could be missing something though.

Comment: This gets too special for this format. Your cell-phone might come with a graphics processor which is optimized for evaluating these $4\times 4$ transformation matrices. You might search for a machine vision lib for your target hardware. E.g. see [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/gpu-accelerated-machine-vision/).